# Spacy Update msvc not found

Tags: python, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, pip, spacy

I'trying to update spacy from version 2.0.18 to version 2.1.1.
But every time I try to run the command

```
pip install spacy-nightly
```

or

```
pip install -U spacy==2.1.1
```

I just get

```
error: [WinError 2] System cannot find file specified
msvc
      py_compiler msvc
```

with a lot of unreadable output.
Now I figured it has something to do with the C++ compiler spacy uses and I installed like every package I found at the Microsoft Visual Website but my problem didnt solve itself.

I really would appreciate some help!

Comment: Are you on Python 2? If so, this might be the problem, since the new version can't support Python 2 on Windows anymore at the moment ([see here](https://spacy.io/usage/v2-1#incompat) for details.) However, if you can use Python 3, you'll be able to install spaCy from a pre-built wheel which requires no local compilers and is super fast.

Comment: I'm on python 3.7.1. Could you maybe explain or send a link how to install spacy from a pre-built wheel? :)

Comment: This should happen automatically when you run `pip install` – it should detect that you're on Windows and Python 3.7, and then serve you the correct `.whl` file [from here](https://pypi.org/project/spacy/#files). If this doesn't work, the quickest workaround would probably be to install spaCy from `conda` (e.g. using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)).

Comment: If that's not possible, you can also try copying the link to `spacy-2.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/spacy/#files) and then running `pip install https://files.pythonhosted...` etc. If it says that the wheel is not supported on the platform, that's definitely suspicious. In that case, you might also want to double-check that you're running 64-bit Python (and not 32-bit).

Comment: with conda everything went well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, you are on a 64-bit machine using a 32-bit python executable. 
Remove the 32-bit version of python and Install the 64 bit version of python it will work.

If you where working within a virtualenv, then delete the virtualenv and recreate it again after installing the 64-bit of python.